# Update WidgetList View

Tags: android, widget

I have a problem updating my Widget ListView, I don't need it to be updated automatically i need to update It according to a button Click in my App which calls an intent services that should update data.
the widget is updated correctly for the first time to click the button only,
and in other clicks Logs shows that data changes correctly but the view is not updated.

i had tried may solution from stackoverflow but all of them didn't work.
**note** 
i don't want to use any database of sharedpreferences

and here is my code gitHub repo for my widget classes

https://github.com/abdelmun3m/BackingApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/abdelmun3m/backingapp/widget

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a PendingIntent on the button that is manually updating the widget, when you create the RemoteViews? This PendingIntent will trigger an onUpdate call on your WidgetPRovider. From there you can spawn the IntentService.

```
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.your_widget_layout);
    ...
    // Initialize listview here
    ...
    Intent refreshIntent = new Intent(context,YourWidgetProvider.class);
    refreshIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    PendingIntent refreshPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REFRESH_PENDING_INTENT_ID, refreshIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.your_refresh_button_id, refreshPendingIntent);
```